# Design decision: class hierarchy or Java 8 Optional

Tags: java, design

I am really reconsidering my current class hierarchy for timeslots (in a schedule). I wanted to make them as flexible as possible so it would cover many possibilities of what we could understand as a timeslot, so I ended up with this design:

All timeslots share a chronological/hierarchical order so we're able to define comparing functions. It provides the most basic means of determining if a timeslot comes before or after another.

```
public interface Timeslot extends Comparable<Timeslot> {
   int getChronologicalOrder();
}
```

This is the "base" timeslot, it just has a chronological order integer.

```
public class AbstractTimeslot extends Entity implements Timeslot {
    protected final int chronologicalOrder;
}
```

This is for timeslots that define a range, that is, the span of the timeslot in the schedule, for example 10 minutes, 1 hours, 3 days, etc... To represent this we use a `TemporalAmount` member. However, the starting point of the timeslot is unknown or irrelevant.

```
public abstract class RangedTimeslot extends AbstractTimeslot {
    protected final TemporalAmount duration;
}
```

Then we have this timeslot which is like the previous one but it does define a definite starting point using the Java 8 interface `TemporalAccessor`. This way we can say when a timeslot starts, like a particular day or hour with `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `DayOfWeek`, etc.

```
public class DefiniteTimeslot extends RangedTimeslot {
    protected final TemporalAccessor start;
}
```

Finally there's this timeslot that doesn't define a duration because it is unknown or irrelevant, but we know the starting time. It is exactly like a `RangedTimeslot` but I wanted to keep this last one as an `abstract` class in case we needed further hierarchy expansion.

```
public class UndefiniteTimeslot extends RangedTimeslot {}
```

Visually, this is how the hierarchy looks like:

[image]

Now I am wondering if this is making things harder than they actually are. The first big wall I am facing with this design is that now I need to serialize and deserialize as JSON many of my classes, like `Tournament` and `Schedule`, and they include these timeslot classes. This kind of polymorphism makes it kind of a hell to deal with serialization and deserialization (I am using Jackson), so I just started wondering if this is a good design and if it'd be a good idea to "simplify" it. I'd still have to face the polymorphism problem of `TemporalAmount` and `TemporalAccessor` but that's kind of inevitable.

I think the other way of thinking this scenario is cutting the whole tree and be left with just a `Timeslot` class with `Optional` members so every situation where we want undefined starting times and/or undefined timeslot span are covered. We would end up with a class more or like the one that follows:

```
public class Timeslot extends Comparable<Timeslot> {
    private int chronologicalOrder;
    private final Optional<TemporalAccessor> start;
    private final Optional<TemporalAmount> duration;

    public Timeslot(int c) {
        chronologicalOrder = c;
        start = Optional.empty();
        duration = Optional.empty();
    }

    public Timeslot(int c, TemporalAccessor s) {
        chronologicalOrder = c;
        start = s;
        duration = Optional.empty();
    }

    public Timeslot(int c, TemporalAmount d) {
        chronologicalOrder = c;
        start = Optional.empty();
        duration = d;
    }

    public Timeslot(int c, TemporalAccessor s, TemporalAmount d) {
        chronologicalOrder = c;
        start = s;
        duration = d;
    }
}
```

What do you think is the best design? Should I dump my current hierarchy and take the last solution? Would it make testing the class easier? (I already have tests for the current design)

Comment: I'm wondering what the ordering of "3 days" and "Next Tuesday" is

Comment: What is your problem with jackson here ? I have no problem doing this with jackson.

Comment: @Caleth although an odd situation, that's why the chronological order exists, it determines the order.

Comment: @Walfrat the problem is not Jackson specific, but serialization/deserialization rather because there are subclasses. However as I mentioned the `TemporalAccessor ` and `TemporalAmount ` serialization/deserialization is a bigger issue that the hierarchy itself, tbh.

Comment: @dabadaba I saw that, but how do you assign chronological order for the two examples I gave? And if the answer is "We write some helper function on `TemporalAccessor s, TemporalAmount d`", how do you expect people using this type to internalise the rules of that function?

Comment: @Caleth I am not sure I understood what you're trying to say. The user assigns the chronological order, it is his responsibility to choose the number. The comparing method defines that a greater chronological order means the timeslot comes after the other. So if the timeslot "3 days" has a ch. order of "1" and the "next tuesday" timeslot has a ch. order of "2", then "3 days" precedes "next tuesday". Weird, but it's up to the user. I just don't want to close doors.

Comment: @dabadaba I am suggesting that because you have to add an artificial ordering member, maybe Timeslot shouldn't be Comparable

Comment: @Caleth Yes they must be comparable. I need to know which timeslot comes before or after another, that's why I came up with that chornological order system. What do you mean with "artificial"? However, this thing we're discussing doesn't seem to be related to my question, does it? I am asking which design is better: a class hierarchy or using optional members.

Comment: I prefer what you're calling the "optionals" approach (I call those "constructor overloads." ) The class hierarchy is to distinguish different kinds of objects, and it doesn't look like that's what you have here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey actually I was suggested the optionals approach, but I wonder... what does that differ from simply leaving a member as `null`? That would mean that it's unknown/irrelevant right? How is using optionals any different?

Comment: Each constructor allow you to set the members not specified in the constructor parameters to any value that is appropriate.

Comment: And what value would be appropriate? In this case, if I create a timeslot using the `public Timeslot(int c, TemporalAccessor s)` constructor, that's because I want a timeslot with a starting time, but I don't care about its duration. My question is, how do I represent that "I don't care about its duration"? This is why I created a hierarchy in the first place, to avoid having information in a class that was totally irrelevant to it. But if we decided to stick with this unique class design, what's the most correct thing to do?

Comment: "timeslot that doesn't define a duration but we know the starting time" - "exactly like a RangedTimeslot" - That's a contradiction. As shown, the whole point of RangedTimeslot is that it knows the duration, but doesn't know the starting time. I think your class hierarchy doesn't make any sense at all, and that alone is reason enough to go with the optionals.

Comment: This inheritance-based design in premature. Go back and write one definite use case. Implement it with the absolute minimum code required. Then write another and implement that, again with the absolute minimum code required. Refactor as necessary. Repeat until all use cases have been implemented. That will probably lead you to a better design.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is "design A or design B?" and my answer is neither.  Actually, I'm going to say that aside from the interface, your Timeslot class doesn't really matter and that both of these designs are a result of coming at this from the wrong direction.

At the risk of overextending an analogy, consider the question: 'what is a slot?'  A slot is a type of hole.  And we all know that the question "how many holes does it take to fill X?" is nonsensical.

Kidding (sort of) aside, you really shouldn't have a public constructor on your timeslot class.  Timeslots are really an attribute of a calendar.  Trying to use them in isolation or trying to build the calendar from (heterogeneous) timeslots is problematic at best.  If I were designing something in this area, I would make the timeslots inner classes or even anonymous inner classes of a schedule class.  Here's an example of how that might look from an API perspective (this could be very different depending on what you need to achieve e.g. are timeslots of fixes size or of varying size):

```
interface Schedule
{
    List<Timeslot> getAvailable()

    boolean reserve(Timeslot timeslot)
}
```

The only place timeslots would be created is within the Schedule object.  This allows the timeslots to be created in a consistent and reliable way.  For example, if the timeslots can be created and passed in, it's harder to avoid getting the same slot created twice or perhaps you might get overlapping slots.

Once you get to this point, you should realize that a timeslot is just a porthole view of the whole schedule and the hierarchy has no need to exist because the structure is based on how the schedule is managed.

Answer (score 0):

Jackons is used to serialize "dumb" POJO, there you have object with intelligence (TemporalAccessor), this is not compatible.

You can :

- move it away on some service layer
- use DTO layer to convert your business entity to a POJO
- Remove empty contructor on higher classes, having one protected constructor which will take the TemporalAccessor implementation in parameter
- Define somewhat a custom serializer/deserializer that will instantiate the right TemporalAccessor this may be tricky and not necessary

I'll develop the 3rd choice, this would give something like :

```
public abstract class RangedTimeslot extends AbstractTimeslot {
    protected final TemporalAmount duration; 
    protected RangedTimeslot(TemporalAmount duration){
       this.duration = duration;
    }
}

public abstract class DefiniteTimeslot extends RangedTimeslot {
    protected final TemporalAccessor start;
     protected DefiniteTimeslot (TemporalAmount duration, TemporalAccessor start){
       super(duration);
       this.start = start;
    }
}

public class MyTimeSlot extends DefiniteTimeslot{
       public MyTimeSlot(){
            // or cached static reference 
            super(new TemporalAmountImpl(), new TemporalAccessorImpl());
       }
}
```

Another way using generics

```
public abstract class RangedTimeslot<T extends TemporalAmount> extends AbstractTimeslot{
    protected RangedTimeslot(T duration){...}
}

public abstract class DefiniteTimeslot<T extends TemporalAmount, U extends TemporalAccessor> extends RangedTimeslot<T>{
      protected DefiniteTimeslot (T duration, U start){}
}

public class MyTimeSlot extends DefiniteTimeslot<TemporalAmountImpl, TemporalAccessorImpl>{
       public MyTimeSlot(){
            // or cached static reference 
            super(new TemporalAmountImpl(), new TemporalAccessorImpl());
       }
}
```

Comment: This wasn't a Jackson question. It's a question to decide if I should stick to my hierarchy or have a unique `Timeslot` class with `Optional` members. Obviously I am not dealing with POJOs, I am implementing my own custom serializers and deserializers, but then again, this is not the scope of my question.

Comment: @dabadaba So the code that i did is not about design ? It has nothing relevant with Jackson yet is compatible. I suggested you others design solution from the Optional.. Is your question is a A or B solution and not C ? If then my bad because i'm suggesting a C/D/... **design** option which are improvment of A. Compatible with Jackson, yet not so relevant with it. Because i don't tihnk Optional is really a good fit here.

Comment: Ok I see your point now, then this is a valid answer. However, I fail to understand your design. So you're suggesting all my timeslot classes are to be `abstract`? And then what? The user should define their own classes that extend from these abstract ones?

Comment: @dabadaba Yes, this is a common pattern with generics. I edited my post and add some code, the same solution, with generics this time. This is supposing that each type will always support only one implementation of those. If not this won't fit.

Comment: so if the user must provide the implementation, must he also provide the custom serializer and deserializer I guess?

Comment: @dabadaba Hum : if you use the generics approach, Jackson will be able to handle serialization/deserialization, because fields will be type TemporalAmountImpl and TemporalAccessorImpl. So for Jackson, there is no polymorphism to handle. Without generics, you will need a way around so the user serialize/Deserialize his own objects.

Comment: I have been chewing on this, I don't get it... How will Jackson know how to serialize an unknown subclass of `TemporalAmount` or `TemporalAccessor`?

Comment: If you look the end of my post with thegenerics, T and U will be respectively replaced by TemporalAmountImpl & TemporalAccesorImpl. So Jackson can handle them.

Comment: But in the class definition I need to define custom serializers and deserializers, and these are not dealing with those interface implementations, but with `TemporalAmount` or `TemporalAccessor` instances... Besides, the deserialization returns an instance, and I of course I can't instantiate abstract classes.